# How to make this image zoom in with animated.css

Tags: css, image, animate.css

I'm  trying to make this  images zoomIn with Animated.css library and with jquery but i don't know how to do it.

---

```
<html>
  <head>
   <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
   <title>Code a Responsive Website with Twitter Bootstrap 3</title>
   <meta name="description" content="Learn how to code your first responsive website with the new Twitter Bootstrap 3.">
   <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css-master/animate.min.css">
   <!-- Custom CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/styles.css">
   <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
   <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div class="row" id="features">
       <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
           <img src="images/badge_css3.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle">
           <p>90's authentic single-origin coffee stumptown Pinterest. Fap aesthetic dreamcatcher pickled Brooklyn irony.</p>
           <a href="https://www.udemy.com/build-beautiful-html5-website/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Learn to code HTML5</a>
       </div>
       <!-- end feature -->
       <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
           <img src="images/badge_css3.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle">
           <p>90's authentic single-origin coffee stumptown Pinterest. Fap aesthetic dreamcatcher pickled Brooklyn irony.</p>
           <a href="https://www.udemy.com/build-beautiful-html5-website/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Style it up with CSS3</a>
       </div>
       <!-- end feature -->
       <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
           <img src="images/badge_bootstrap.jpg" alt="Bootstrap 3" class="img-circle" id="closeButton">
           <p>90's authentic single-origin coffee stumptown Pinterest. Fap aesthetic dreamcatcher pickled Brooklyn irony.</p>
           <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block">More Bootstrap</a>
       </div>
       <!-- end features -->
     </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

how to make the images with class img-circle zoomIn when the user click on the images

Comment: this is th images   <img src="images/badge_css3.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle       ">

Answer (score 0):

You need to include animated.css file in the head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css">
```

or you can get the animated.css from here.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

Comment: i know this is not my problem  i wont know how to write the jqery cod with image element and add class  animated zoomIn when the user click in the images with the class     img-circle

Comment: This can be done without using animated.css with see this http://jsfiddle.net/rhulkashyap/761053ed/6/

Comment: @RahulKashyap, this comment is actually a different answer. Please make a new answer with this content. By the way, in a new answer you can add a snippet with this code - it's better way.

Comment: can any one help m eplz